TypeScript error: `_id` field doesn't exist on Mongoose subdocument
I'm using Mongoose with TypeScript and TypeScript is not able to infer that subdocuments have an _id field.
I've two Mongoose models:
// User.ts

export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true }
});

export default model('User', UserSchema);

// Score.ts

export const ScoreSchema = new Schema({
    score: { type: Number, required: true },
    owner: { type: UserSchema, required: true },
});

export default model('Score', ScoreSchema);

This is the code that uses the Score model:
const score = await Score.findById(id);
if (score.owner._id.toString() === adminId) { // TypeScript error occurs here: field `_id` doesn't exist
    console.log("Admin mode");
}

Field _id does exist on the object returned by findById. How can I setup Mongoose/TypeScript/my schemas so that this error disappears.

That because of "owner" is type of UserSchema.
And here is your user schema:
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true }
});

UserSchema has no property named with _id. You may want to specify that.
OR you can create an interface for owner with property _id and give that type on your score schema.
